# exception occured in C++ function

Tags: c++

When given the number "n" and its radix "D", the function followed is used to calculate its reversed number under radix D, and then convert to Decimal and return.

The problem is that, the method 1 can work succefully while method 2 always comes up with an exception. Is there anyone to tell me what's the problem with method 2 ? Thanks very much.

```
int getrevn(int n, int D)

{
//-------method 1-------------------------//

    int revn = 0;
    while (n)
    {
        revn = revn * D + n % D;
        n /= D;
    }
    return revn;

//------method 2-------------------------//

    string s;
    while (n)
    {
        s = char(n % D + '0') + s;
        n /= D;
    }
    int rev = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        rev = rev * D + s[i] - '0';
    return rev;
}
```

Comment: What's the exception? That's kind of important.

Comment: In method 2, `s` was just declared, but not initialized so you can't have `+ s`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: How is `string s;` uninitialized?

Comment: @IInspectable Wouldn't it have to be set to an empty string literal?

Comment: @EliSadoff: What would be the rationale for that? Re-doing, what the default c'tor just did? Why?

Comment: I thought that there was some benefit to setting it equal to an empty literal, but I could have just learned that incorrectly.

Comment: i thought when declaring a string, it is initialized to an empty string defaultly.

Comment: even when i changed the declare of string s to " string s = ""  ", the problem still exist.

Comment: Since you got an exception I assume you are running (and compiling) on Windows. In that case, I will assume, that you are using Visual Studio. In that case, get in the habit of using the *Run Code Analysis on Solution* feature. Output here: `warning C6295: Ill-defined for-loop:  'unsigned int' values are always of range '0' to '4294967295'.  Loop executes infinitely.`

Answer (score 0):

In your last loop, you're declaring `i` as unsigned.  So `i` will always be `>= 0`, and your loop won't terminate.

Instead, `i` will just wrap around to a very large number, which causes the crash.  Just change `i` to signed.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out, that the code exhibits *undefined behavior*, and a compiler/platform is free to show **any** observable behavior (including non at all). An exception is not guaranteed to happen, and if it is thrown, it's most certainly not a C++ exception. More likely, however, is a silent heap corruption.